# How to set a field value into a saved entity in MyBatis?

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

Here is my save method for an entity. It checks a null value of a non-nullable field `surcharge` which has 'true' default value in my DB:

```
<insert id="saveBundle" parameterType="Bundle">
        <selectKey keyColumn="id" keyProperty="id" resultType="long" order="BEFORE">
            select nextval('bundle_id_seq')
        </selectKey>
        insert into bundle(id, created, config_bundle_id, client_id, pif_type, renew_date,
        status, status_at, agreement, config_plan_id, processing_status, pre_payment_check, pre_payment_check_at,
        updated_at, renew_date_at <if test="surcharge != null">, surcharge</if>)
        VALUES (
        #{id,jdbcType=BIGINT},
        #{created,jdbcType=TIMESTAMP},
        #{configBundleId,jdbcType=BIGINT},
        #{clientId,jdbcType=BIGINT},
        #{pifType,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{renewDate,jdbcType=TIMESTAMP},
        #{status, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{statusAt,jdbcType=TIMESTAMP},
        #{agreement,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{configPlanId,jdbcType=BIGINT},
        #{processingStatus,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{prePaymentCheck,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{prePaymentCheckAt, jdbcType=TIMESTAMP},
        #{updatedAt, jdbcType=TIMESTAMP},
        #{renewDateAt, jdbcType=TIMESTAMP}
        <if test='surcharge != null'>, #{surcharge, jdbcType=BOOLEAN}</if>
        )
    </insert>
```

Here is the interface method:

```
void saveBundle(Bundle bundle);
```

Sometimes I need to save my entity and then check the `surcharge` param. I don't set the value using the setter, so MyBatis sets it as 'true' in my DB table.
The request doesn't set the param to the entity, only to database.
Is it possible to set the param into the entity using only myBatis mapper/interface or request without using the entity setter?

Comment: When the app doesn't set the value of `surcharge` then we can assume it's a Java null. Then, when the mapper is executed, the INSERT won't include the column and the database will automatically apply the default value for the column. MyBatis or the Java app don't really know what value was actually inserted by the database. There are some engines that can return the inserted row, though, using `RETURNING`; that effectively converts the INSERT into a SELECT.